# Convert application using wifi to application using bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, android-wifi

I have an android app, it does the following:

Connects with a server to read and update a database at the same time as others.

I want to convert this to an app that does not need an internet connection. Therefore i would like to know if its possible to have an android device acting as the server with the database, whilst multiple phones connect to it via bluetooth getting and updating the information in the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It possible.

However all of your devices will have to be located nearby, so they can connect to each other through bluetooth.

You can take a look at [Android Bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

However, my recommendation would be to use Wifi instead of Bluetooth. YOu will need additional WiFi router. However, you won't need to deal with Bluetooth API in such case.

You will only need to write a server on one of Android device and the rest of devices will work the same (as now)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, The reason for me wanting to use bluetooth is it is a game that you will always be right next to the other people playing. Developed it using wi-fi as found it easier but wanted to add usage as people may want to play when no internet available. just thought there may be a problem with concurrency and having multiple phones connected via bluetooth be quite slow?

Comment: You may have problems with initial device pairing and also, if number of devices will become high you will have a problem. I read somewhere that you can have maximum 8 devices in pico network. P.S. I would appreciate, if you can upvote my answer :)

Comment: I would but don't have enough reputation, sorry bro

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to doing so, that don't involve a server. Both of them require a slightly different approach than both devices connecting to a server.

1. Wi-fi Direct- Only available with Android 4.0+.
2. Bluetooth

Personally, I have been using the Bluetooth option, and not found it terribly difficult. Essentially, you have to do the following to make it work.

1. Have one of the devices listen for a connection. If it is unpaired, you will have to make the device discoverable.
2. The second device needs to initiate a connection. It can do this by looking at the known devices and trying to connect to one, or listening for a new device
3. After the two devices connect, they must initiate some kind of a communication protocol. The communication is essential a serial connection.

Blue-tooth requires that the devices be within about 10 m of each other. Wi-fi direct will allow somewhat further, but as mentioned, is less supported. It is possible to allow for both communication methods, but is somewhat challenging.